# ScaleTransition animation with FadeTransition inside doesn't work correctly

Tags: flutter, animation

I'm trying to animate a widget with `ScaleTransition` and `FadeTransition` at the same time and this аnimation is not working properly. It works fine only first time. Scale animation some times works randomly or it depends how fast you push the button.

[image]

Here the simple reproduction code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: LogoScale(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LogoScale extends StatefulWidget {
  const LogoScale({super.key});

  @override
  State<LogoScale> createState() => LogoScaleState();
}

class LogoScaleState extends State<LogoScale> {
  bool show = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: (){
            setState(() {
              show = !show;
            });
          },
          child: Text(show ? 'Hide Logo' : 'Show Logo'),
        ),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            AnimationInOut(
                show: show,
                child: const FlutterLogo(size: 100.0,)
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class AnimationInOut extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool show;
  final Widget child;

  const AnimationInOut({super.key,
    required this.show,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  State<AnimationInOut> createState() => AnimationInOutState();
}

class AnimationInOutState extends State<AnimationInOut> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Animation<double> scaleAnimation;
  late Animation<double> fadeAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    animationController.value = widget.show ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    scaleAnimation = animationController.drive(Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0));
    fadeAnimation = animationController.drive(Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(AnimationInOut oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if(widget.show){
      animationController.forward();
    }else{
      animationController.reverse();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaleTransition(
      scale: scaleAnimation,
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: fadeAnimation,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I ran your example and saw the same issue. I swapped the FadeTransition and ScaleTransition to see if it was always prioritizing the second widget's animation, and it was working consistently.

so instead of

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaleTransition(
      scale: scaleAnimation,
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: fadeAnimation,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
```

do

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FadeTransition(
      opacity: fadeAnimation,
      child: ScaleTransition(
        scale: scaleAnimation,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }
```